# Configuring mod_wsgi for python3 on Redhat 7

Tags: python, mod-wsgi

I am trying to configure an Apache Server to host my Flask API's using WSGI and Apache.

I have installed Apache 2.4.6 on Redhat 7, but the default python version for mod_wsgi is python 2.7 .

I have been following this guide : https://curiousdba.netlify.app/post/djangoonrhel7/

I installed mod_wsgi module for python3 using:

```
pip3 install mod_wsgi
```

But I encounter an error when using:

```
mod_wsgi-express install-module> /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/02-wsgi.conf

bash: mod_wsgi-express : command not found..
```

Any idea how I can work on this.

I have also tried installing `rh-python36-mod_wsgi` using yum package manager but it couldn't find any such package.

Comment: 1. Did you check the requirements for https://pypi.org/project/mod-wsgi/ ? 2. You need to enable RH Software Collections to get the RPM: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_software_collections/3/html/3.8_release_notes/chap-installation and the Python version might be different in the meantime, e.g. rh-python38-....

Answer (score 1):

To get Python 3+ working with mod_wsgi in CentOS you can do this:

> yum install httpd-devel

( if you use Apache)

Then :

try this one for python 3.6:

> yum install python36u-mod_wsgi

and for python 3.8 :

> yum install python38-mod_wsgi

Comment: yum list \*mod_wsgi\* only returns the mod_wsgi package.

Comment: You can add any repository to yum configuration (seek inside `/etc/yum/conf.d/repo.conf` or similar config files in that config directory, and after an update of the referenced repositories `yum update`, you can run your `yum install python38-mod_wsgi`.

Answer (score 0):

> If you are using Linux, macOS or other UNIX type operating system, and
> you don’t have Apache available, you can instead install mod_wsgi
> using:
>
> `pip install mod_wsgi-standalone`
>
> When installing `mod_wsgi-standalone`, it will also install a version of
> Apache into your Python distribution. You can only use
> `mod_wsgi-express` when using this variant of the package. The
> `mod_wsgi-standalone` package follows the same version numbering as the
> mod_wsgi package on PyPi.

**You can only use mod_wsgi-express when using this variant of the package**.

> On a UNIX type system, to verify that the installation was successful,
> run the `mod_wsgi-express` script with the start-server command:
>
> `mod_wsgi-express start-server`
>
> This will start up Apache/mod_wsgi on port 8000. You can then verify
> that the installation worked by pointing your browser at:
>
> `http://localhost:8000/`
>
> When started in this way, the Apache web server will stay in the
> foreground. To stop the Apache server, use CTRL-C.

https://pypi.org/project/mod-wsgi/

**Update**

There's a package for CentOS 7 at https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/python3-mod_wsgi-4.7.1-2.el7.x86_64.rpm.html

And `mod_wsgi-express` is located at **/usr/bin/mod_wsgi-express-3**

Install Howto

1. Download latest epel-release rpm from

   http://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/
2. Install epel-release rpm:

   `# rpm -Uvh epel-release*rpm`
3. Install python3-mod_wsgi rpm package:

   `# yum install python3-mod_wsgi`

Comment: I already have Apache installed and I am really reluctant to install another as it is owned by my corporation.

Comment: "You can only use mod_wsgi-express when using this variant of the package.' - from the doc.

Comment: @prog_SAHIL updated answer for new source for rpm package.